# Mongodb find with objectid in ballerina

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, ballerina, wso2-choreo

In this case I have seen the official documentation of choreo, ballerina, but I could not find how to execute a query where I need to filter by the `ObjectId`, In Java I could do it by importing BSON, but I could not find the same in ballerina.

In the following example, it does not give an error, because that field is mapped to that type.

```
//map<json> queryString = {user_id: new object"61b75a0a08f2bf69b98a174c" };
        
map<json> queryString = {unique_id: 1 };
        map<json> projectionDoc = {unique_id: true, destination_address: true, _id: true};
        stream<Historial, error?> h_viajes = check mongoClient->find(collectionName = "trip_histories",projection = projectionDoc,filter = queryString);
        check h_viajes.forEach(function(Historial datas){
                io:println(datas.unique_id.toString());
                io:println(datas._id.toString());
                log:printInfo(datas.unique_id.toString());
            });
```

Comment: I have opened a public issue to track the documentation gap, https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-extended-library/issues/476

Answer (score 0):

Ballerina changes json string to BSON object. For this purpose, the filterQuery has to be compatible with [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). The correct filter for ObjectId type will be,

```
map<json> queryString = {_id: {"$oid": "<ObjectId>"}};
map<json> queryString = {_id: {"$oid": "63789aed271ba8943ff92574"}};
```

`{"$oid": "<ObjectId>"}` can be used for any field of type `ObjectId`.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic casting of a string to **The 12-byte ObjectId** data type is not available in Ballerina, however it is possible to build it using the JSON notation provided by [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

***For example:***

```
map<json> filtersFields = {user_id: {"$oid": "60744b37d9bc8741f6edb714"}};
```

And through this syntax it is possible to filter by any field that is of type ObjectId